# C - Is there anyway to pass a string / array of strings from one function to another without using global variables?

Tags: c, string

I created an array of strings using malloc in a function. Is there anyway i can use that string in main or in any other function? Do i need to pass it from the function back to main? Could somone pelase provide an example?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void lineParse();

int main()
{
    lineParse();    
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

void lineParse()
{
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("specification.txt", "r");

    char ** listofdetails; 
    listofdetails = malloc(sizeof(char*)*6);

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        listofdetails[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
        fgets(listofdetails[i], 40, fp);
        /*printf("%s \n", listofdetails[i]);*/
        /*free(listofdetails[i]);*/
    }


    char ** stringOne; 
    stringOne = malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

    stringOne[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringOne[0] = strtok(listofdetails[0], " ");

    for(i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        stringOne[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        stringOne[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    char ** stringTwo; 
    stringTwo = malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

    stringTwo[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringTwo[0] = strtok(listofdetails[1], " ");

    for(i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
        stringTwo[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        stringTwo[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    char ** stringThree; 
    stringThree = malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

    stringThree[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringThree[0] = strtok(listofdetails[2], " ");

    for(i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        stringThree[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        stringThree[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    char ** stringFour; 
    stringFour= malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

    stringFour[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringFour[0] = strtok(listofdetails[3], " ");

    for(i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        stringFour[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        stringFour[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    char ** stringFive; 
    stringFive= malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

    stringFive[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringFive[0] = strtok(listofdetails[4], " ");

    for(i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        stringFive[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        stringFive[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    char ** stringSix; 
    stringSix= malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

    stringSix[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringSix[0] = strtok(listofdetails[5], " ");

    for(i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        stringSix[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        stringSix[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    free(listofdetails);
    free(stringOne);
    free(stringTwo);
    free(stringThree);
    free(stringFour);
    free(stringFive);
    free(stringSix);
    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: Yes: `char ** lineParse() { .... return listofdetails;}` Just noticed all the frees at the end. You can't return a pointer you've already freed.

Comment: There's an awful lot of repetition in that code; you should be looking to reduce it.  You can return a pointer to dynamically allocated memory (which may, in turn, point to other dynamically allocated memory, and so on) from your function.  Since you free a number of pointers (but by no means everything -- your code leaks horribly, unless I'm misreading something), it isn't clear what you need to return.

Comment: I can't help but notice this code looks *veeerrrry* similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328136/how-to-pass-a-string-from-a-fuction-to-main/25328214) question...

Comment: @Drew: same but not similar. This one spells "function" correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, passing things like string arrays around without using global variables is quite easy in C. Of course, *you have to be very careful about memory leaks, buffer overruns, and all that usual C stuff* though. Below is a complete example to

- create and return a string array
- pass the string array to a function for using it
- free the string array

What you need to do with your own code is, you need to make your `lineParse()` function similar to `dummy_string_array()` function below. Note that the strings are not freed in that function, they are freed only, when they are no longer needed.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// return a dummy NULL-terminated string array with given number of strings
char **dummy_string_array(unsigned length)
{
    char **ret = malloc(sizeof(char*) * length + 1);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < length ; ++i) {
        ret[i] = malloc(i + 1); // allocate NUL-terminated char array AKA string
        char filler = (i % ('Z'-'A'+1)) + 'A'; // filler char cycles A...Z A...Z
        memset(ret[i], filler, i); // fill with increasing length of single filler char
        ret[i][i] = '\0'; // end of string marker
    }
    ret[length] = NULL; // marks end of array
    return ret;
 }

// print a NULL-terminated string array
void print_string_array(char **string_array)
{
    // loop with integer index
    for(unsigned i = 0; string_array[i]; ++i) {
        printf("%u :'%s'\n", i, string_array[i]);
    }
 }


// free a NULL-terminated string array
void free_string_array(char **string_array)
{
    // loop with pointer, until NULL pointer
    for(char **ptr = string_array; *ptr; ++ptr) {
        free(*ptr); // free the char array AKA string
    }
    free(string_array); // free the string array
}

int main()
{
    char **string_array = dummy_string_array(30);
    print_string_array(string_array);
    free_string_array(string_array);
    // note: string_array is now a dangling pointer
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: The `print_string_array` above takes pointer to pointer to char, but it really *should* take pointer to const pointer to const char (`const char * const *`), because it's not going to modify the string array or the strings in it. But I left it as simple `char **` to keep code easier to understand.

Answer (score -4):

No, you can not.

It is the variable scope.

Variables declared in the function cannot be accessed outside the function. You could use global variables (not recommended) or pointers (very much recommended).

Comment: I am not sure why someone voted this down.  Technically a variable could be passed the to the function (a pointer to a pointer) and mains copy of the pointer could be used as long as the memory was not freed.  As asked the variable could not be used however.

Comment: Whomever is down voting please comment.

Comment: @ojblass Asking why somebody downvoted, usually causes the contrary effect. Also known as the 3rd law of Stack Overflow. Anyway, thanks ojblass, you seem like a cool guy.

Comment: Nice logo you have there... check mine out.

Comment: My work blocks chat rooms...

Comment: You work as a programmer, man that's nice. My dream literally.

Comment: Downvotes are probably because this answer is plain wrong. There are at least two ways to pass and return arrays (including strings) from functions: structs and pointers, and mixing them in various ways.

Comment: Find me on linked in.  Oscar Blass.

Comment: @hyde "I created an array of strings using malloc in a function. Is there anyway i can use that string in main or in any other function?" This was the question, can you use the string declared in a function outside of it. I proposed global variables and pointers. Although it is probably partially wrong it is not plain wrong.

Comment: Malloced memory is not tied to the scope it is allocated at, it is not a variable. Pointers can be passed around as values. Code has no function scope arrays, which would be the closest thing to "string declaration" in C. Global variables are evil. So yes, the answer is wrong on many levels.